# Не открывается кнопка "войти с помощью google". В Android Studio с помощью firebase authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, мобильная-разработка, firebase-android

При написании кода в Android Studio хотел сделать кнопку входа с помощью Google, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

```
class SignInAct : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var launcher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        auth= Firebase.auth
        launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                if(account != null){
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException){
                Log.d("Mylog", "При подключении возникла ошибка")
            }
        }
        binding.bSignIn.setOnClickListener{
            signInWithGoogle()
        }
    }

    private fun getClient(): GoogleSignInClient{
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
    }

    private fun signInWithGoogle(){
        val signInClient = getClient()
        launcher.launch(signInClient.signInIntent)
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idtoken: String){
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idtoken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                Log.d("Mylog", "Вход через Google прошел успешно")
            } else {
                Log.d("Mylog", "Вход через Google не удался")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Вот такие ошибки в логах:**

```
2022-04-12 12:24:05.664 23722-28120/? E/SignInPerformer-6: Game (com.example.chatparadox) failed to include the Play Games Services application id in their AndroidManifest [CONTEXT service_id=1 ]
2022-04-12 12:24:05.664 23722-28120/? E/PlayGamesServices[SignInPerformer]: The Play Games Services application ID is missing from the Android Manifest. For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
     https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags
```

```
2022-04-12 12:24:42.250 1760-2442/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2022-04-12 12:24:43.098 19031-27052/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2022-04-12 12:24:49.167 1874-1874/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2022-04-12 12:24:56.458 19031-28134/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2022-04-12 12:27:47.254 23722-28340/? E/SignInPerformer-8: Game (com.example.chatparadox) failed to include the Play Games Services application id in their AndroidManifest [CONTEXT service_id=1 ]
```

Comment: А в логах по этому поводу что написано?

Comment: Добавил ошибку в логе к вопросу.

Comment: Почему вы решили что имеет какое-то отношение к вашему приложению?

Comment: Я только учусь писать на kotlin и мобильные приложения вообщем.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Спасибо понял как читать логи,и я скинул ошибки.

Comment: Вот это можно почитать: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#check_your_metadata_tags